Failed to create a worklet. See https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/guides/troubleshooting#failed-to-create-a-worklet
Test Code under Home.js which is using a plugin @gorhom/bottom-sheet for bottom sheet.

import React, { useCallback, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import BottomSheet, { BottomSheetView } from '@gorhom/bottom-sheet';

const Home = () => {
  // ref
  const bottomSheetRef = useRef(null);

  // callbacks
  const handleSheetChanges = useCallback((index) => {
    console.log('handleSheetChanges', index);
  }, []);

  // renders
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <BottomSheet
        ref={bottomSheetRef}
        onChange={handleSheetChanges}
      >
        <BottomSheetView style={styles.contentContainer}>
          <Text>Awesome </Text>
        </BottomSheetView>
      </BottomSheet>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 24,
    backgroundColor: 'grey',
  },
  contentContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});

export default Home;

///This is my babel config
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ["module:react-native-dotenv", {
      "envName": "APP_ENV",
      "moduleName": "@env",
      "path": ".env",
      "safe": false,
      "allowUndefined": true,
      "verbose": false
    }]
  ]
};

Getting this error
Error: [Reanimated] Failed to create a worklet. See https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/guides/troubleshooting#failed-to-create-a-worklet for more details., js engine: hermes
LOG  Running "Brightiets" with {"rootTag":21}
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "Brightiets" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

Follow the troubleshooting provided in the software mansions website related this but no use. upgraded all the plugins to latest but no use
